# Is it safe to render Html that was uploaded as Markdown and converted serverside to Html?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, markdown, html-encode

I have a webform that allows users to upload text as Markdown.

The Markdown is converted to Html on the server(using Markdig) and also stored.

When displaying the converted Html that the user uploaded, should I @Html.Encode the content - the project is in c#, MVC 5/razor with request validation on.

Comment: Alternatively, is it safe to just call Html.Raw on the converted Html that the user uploaded?

Comment: For a good review of this issue and how to address it see: [Markdown and XSS](https://michelf.ca/blog/2010/markdown-and-xss/). While that addresses a PHP library, the principles and concepts should apply to any language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't.

I just trivially tested the following:

```
<a href="javascript:evil()">hello</a>
```

and `markdig` lets it through:

See [online example](https://babelmark.github.io/?text=Hello%20**Markdig**!%20%3Ca%20href%3D%22javascript%3Aevil()%22%3Ehello%3C%2Fa%3E).

Although I haven't looked into it too deeply, the [Microsoft AntiXSS library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiXSS/) might be useful here:

```
var safeHtml = Microsoft.Security.Application.Sanitizer
    .GetSafeHtmlFragment("<a href='javascript:evil()'>hello</a>");
```

gives:

```
<a href="">hello</a>
```

but

```
var safeHtml = Microsoft.Security.Application.Sanitizer
    .GetSafeHtmlFragment("<a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>hello</a>");
```

gives:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">hello</a>
```

Comment: first off thanks! So a follow up question is how to make it safe. This particular script doesn't get past MVC request validation so this case shouldn't arise. Can you point out any best practise examples to make it safe? Does anyone know how Stackoverflow validate their user input before rendering it?

Comment: @Will See the revisions to my answer.

Comment: @Will BTW, the MVC "dangerous input" validation ain't worth s**t. Don't rely on it.

Comment: @Will It seems that [AntiXSS is EOLed](https://wpl.codeplex.com/). I'm sure you can find something similar (whitelist approaches seem like the sanest).

Comment: Thanks for the helping @spender

Comment: For others reading this, in the end I used https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

Answer (score 8):

Generally it depends on the markdown converter.

By default *Markdig* doesn't escape html. You can however use the `DisableHtml` function in the pipeline that escapes all remaining HTML encodable strings that were not processed by previous extensions. This should also give better performance than letting an anti-xss function run over the string again.

See example:

```
var pipeline = new MarkdownPipelineBuilder().DisableHtml().Build();
var result = Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml("<a href='javascript:evil()'>hello</a>", pipeline);
```