# Using Markdig in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, markdown, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I've got strings from a database which are actually 'markdown' strings (strings using markdown syntax).

What is a good way to implement/use this in an asp.net core mvc website.
Should I go with this:

controller:

```
public class FooController : Controller 
{
   private static MarkdownPipeline _Pipeline = new MarkdownPipelineBuilder().UseAdvancedExtensions().Build();
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
      // ...
      var vm = new FooViewModel();
      vm.Title = foo.Title;
      string htmlDescription = Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml(foo.Description, _Pipeline);
      vm.Description = Microsoft.Security.Application.Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(htmlDescription);

      return View(vm);
    }

}
```

view:

```
  @Html.Raw(Model.Description);
```

Is an htmlhelpertag similar to this a better solution? https://blog.maximerouiller.com/post/creating-a-simple-aspnet-5-markdown-taghelper/

Or should this conversion logic be implemented in the viewmodel itself instead of in the controller actionmethods?

The GetSafeHtmlFragment uses the Microsoft AntiXSS library.
For the markdown I'm using the Markdig package.

Comment: You can add .DisableHtml() to the pipeline build
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43090491/is-it-safe-to-render-html-that-was-uploaded-as-markdown-and-converted-serverside/50345280